# conditionally setting and conditionally using a variable python

Tags: python, convention

I know it is bad convention/design to conditionally declare a variable. i.e.:

```
if some_boolean:
   x = 1
```

where x is not declared anywhere else. But is it bad to conditionally declare a variable if you only use it later on if that condition is met?

```
if some_boolean and some_other_boolean:
   x+=1
```

Comment: I don't think that this is 'bad' at all. I think that it might be a sign that you should split classes or functions into smaller components but sometimes, thats not feasible. Did you have a particular case in mind?

Comment: It's just my script allows the user to specify options. It's just depending on the option, my script does different things both at the beginning and the end of the script.

Comment: I definitely agree that it points to bad modularity in the code. Are you familiar with [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)? Posting a sample of your code might help us point you to how it might be refactored.

Answer (score 2):

It's dubious style, as it's prone to bugs based on imperfect, impartial understanding on some future maintainer's part.  I also think that initially setting variables to `None` (unless more useful values are known for them) is helpful to readability, in part because it gives you one, natural place to document all of the variables with comments (rather than spreading such comments all over the place, which makes them hard to find;-).

Answer (score 1):

if your code look like this

```
if some_boolean:
   x = 1
# some actions
# not changing some_boolean
# but calculating some_other_boolean
# ...
if some_boolean and some_other_boolean:
   x+=1
```

Can it be refactored to

```
def some_actions(some_args,...):
#...
def calculate_some_other_boolean(some_other_args,...):
#...
if some_boolean:
    x = 1
    some_actions(some_args,...)
    if calculate_some_other_boolean(some_other_args,...):
        x+=1
else:
    some_actions(some_args,...)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

From a very simple design perspective, I'd just default the boolean to `false` even if it maybe won't be used later.  That way the boolean in question is not *maybe* defined or *maybe* actually a boolean value, and in the event that it *is* used, it has a proper value.

If you have two or three booleans set to `false` and they never get used, it's not going to make any significant difference in a big picture sense.  If you have more than a few, though, it may indicate a design problem.